# Why is the destructor being called in this code?

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I'm reading my Data Structures book on how to implement an ArrayList, and I have the following code for the erase function:

```
template <typename T>
void ArrayList<T>::erase(int index) {

    //Delete the element whose index is "index"
    //Throw illegalIndex exception if no such element 
    checkIndex(index);



    std::copy(dynArr+ index + 1, dynArr + listSize, dynArr + index);

    dynArr[--listSize].~T(); //invoke destructor


}
```

The destructor is defined as:

```
template<typename T>
ArrayList<T>::~ArrayList() {


delete [] dynArr;


}
```

I'm sort of confused as to what exactly is going on there. Isn't the destructor just there to delete the whole array when it needs to be deleted?

Comment: You call the destructor of an element of your dynArr not the destructor of your class ArrayList

Comment: Note that you should almost never see this type of code in the real world. Let the compiler call the destructor for you 99.99% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor of T is called (not the destructor of `ArrayList<T>`) and it is likely because the objects of type T where created on a preallocated array and not individually on the heap using the special `placement new operator`

So when one is removed there is no need to release any memory but you want to call the destructor so state will be cleaned up

The placement new operator allows constructing an object given an address in memory. This allows libraries (such as std::vector) to allocate a block of memory for future constructs. And using the placement new operator build class instances in a specific location on that block: `void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) throw();`

However when you want to remove an object you can't `delete` it since it does not own the memory but you still call the destructor so it will clean up its own state.
**AFAIK** this is the only use case where it is proper to call the dtor directly

**EDIT**
Explanation to comment why the destructor is called on the last object and not on index:

std::copy will 'copy' the objects using their assignment operator kinda like this:

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
OutputIterator copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result)
{
   while (first!=last) {
      *result = *first;
      ++result; ++first;
   }
   return result;
}
```

So the operator= of objects will be called lots of times.
The object at place index will be written over with the object at place index+1. You expect a proper assignment implementation to both release its own resources and make exact copies of the target resources.
When you complete this operation you end up with a proper array where the last two elements are exact copies of each other and you use the destructor to clean up the last element.

NOTE: The performance of this can probably be improved considering c++11 move semantics instead of std::copy (like boost move algorithm `boost::move`)

NOTE2: If you hold a pointer to an element in the list at a location >index it will point to the wrong element after a change of this sort.

Comment: hmm..so the destructor is just taking care of the element at the index that I chose to erase in the function? Because when I read dynArr[--listSize], it makes me think it's destroying the element at dynArr[--listSize], but that's not the same as destroying the element at the index that I put as an argument into the function. Shouldn't the destructor destroy the element first, AND THEN use copy to shift the elements one position left? @odedsh

Comment: See EDIT to understand why the code is correct in "destorying" the last element and not the element at index.

However if anybody is holding a pointer to an element in the ArrayList it will be the wrong element after this change